# Trying to connect to SQL Server on gcp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've created a new SQL Server instance and database on `GCP`. The "Overview" tab shows the following info:

Connect to this instance

Public IP address: 35.223.145.123

Instance connection name: my-quest-263123:us-central1:my-instance-1

The connections tab has "Public IP" checked. I was able to "Add Network" on this tab with my public ip address. An instruction next to the Network input says "Use `CIDR` notation."  I wasn't able to figure out how to do this offhand but this input accepted my standard public `IP` address.  `SSL` is not enabled/required for this connection.

I updated the password for the SQL Server user on the Users tab and attempted to login to this SS instance via SSMS with:

```
Server name = my-quest-263123:us-central1:my-instance-1
Authentication = "SQL Server Authentication"
Login = sqlserver
Password = (sqlserver password)
```

However, I wasn't able to connect to the instance using this approach. I also created a new User for my `GCP` `SQL` instance but I wasn't able to connect to the instance with this new user either. Any idea what I might be missing here?

Comment: Be sure your public ip address you added to the whitelist is correct. CIRD notation is just to define a range of ips, you can add /0 at the end to specify just yours. Also when you connect shouldn't you use the instance public ip ?

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea what I might be missing here?

Please bear in mind that Cloud SQL with SQL server is still in beta and it may cause unexpected behaviors. If you have the option, you could always change to use MySQL or PostgreSQL.

As for your actual set up, I highly recommend you to follow the next tutorials since you will find out how to connect to your SQL server instance with SSMS and with the command-line through the Cloud Shell:

- If you would like to do local testing, you could use the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/sql-proxy#install) and refer to this [documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/quickstart-proxy-test)
- If you would like to use SSMS you can always follow the next [documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/quickstart)

Following either of those tutorials you should be able to connect successfully to your SQL server instance.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For connecting SSMS to a Cloud SQL for SQL Server instance, the recommended approach is to use the Cloud SQL Proxy, which gives you a secure SSL connection to the database. Here's a blog post that covers how to do that, let me know if you have any questions: [Managing SQL Server instances in Cloud SQL](https://medium.com/google-cloud/managing-sql-server-instances-in-cloud-sql-ecee1e48aa4e).